# Fireball XL5 / Stingray crossover?

Tags: gerry-anderson, fireball-xl5, stingray

In the Gerry Anderson series Fireball XL5 and Stingray, are there any links between the World Space Patrol (based at Space City, and located on an unnamed island in the South Pacific) and the World Aquanaut Security Patrol (based at Marineville, and located somewhere on the West Coast of the United States)?

There was certainly one story in the TV 21 that featured both organisations (and that I think also included a *pre-Thunderbirds* Lady Penelope).

Comment: You're referring to TV21 issues #141 – #149, specifically the "[Unity City](https://operationmegaventures.wordpress.com/2015/02/17/captain-scarlet-unity-city/)" story arc.

Comment: @Valorum Thinking of TV21 issues around #22, where the cover had the story "Zodiac sends for Stingray" during the Astran War.

Comment: Not strictly related to the above question, but check out the following youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seqZLwHm5iw
Gives an interesting link between Stingray and Thunderbirds

Comment: TV21 treated all Anderson's shows as taking place in the same universe, which threw up some odd anomalies - for instance space technology in Fireball XL5 (regular flights to other planets) is far in advance on that in Thunderbirds.(first expedition to Mars). But the only official on-screen crossover was that Zero-X, as seen in the first Thunderbirds film making that first Mars flight, reappeared in the pilot episode of Captain Scarlet.