# Gerry Anderson universe links

Tags: gerry-anderson

Motivated by this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133684/fireball-xl5-stingray-crossover#comment663915_133684), are there any other links mentioned between other in either the TV 21 stories (comic or annuals) and TV shows (see the comment by GordonD)?

For example, this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seqZLwHm5iw)  (that is "The official YouTube account of Anderson Entertainment & the Gerry Anderson Estate" and likely to be more permanent than most web sites) gives some glimpses on the links between *Thunderbirds* and *Stingray*. Also, in her last story, Lady Penelope, battled the Hood and made contact with Jeff Tracey and Brains.

Comment: I always thought Lady Penelope was a field agent for International Rescue. Surely she would meet Jeff Tracey and Brains many times?

Comment: @DannyMcG No, she was independent originally and only seems to have first met them in her final story though when Jeff Tracy is first introduces she has at least met him previously but it isn't specified when and why.

Comment: in the tv series Thunderbirds, Lady Penelope does seem to be a full time agent for \International Rescue